# Is the C# compiler considered to be a part of the .net framework?

Tags: .net-framework

According to articles such as [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh425099.aspx), the .net framework consists of the class library and the CLR. However I also know that the C# compiler comes along, when you download the .net framework.

Officially are the C# and VB compilers considered a part of the .net framework?

Comment: interestingly, as an interpreted family of languages, like java, the sdk contains a compiler that creates an assembly code (MSIL in this case), which at execute time is compiled into native instructions, so yes the .net framework contains a compiler, but not the one you would think. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275360/is-net-vm-a-compiler-or-an-interpreter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the compilers are not part of the .NET framework.  The Frameworks are pre-compiled binaries that other programs need if they were created using .NET.  If you are looking for the .NET compilers, you can get them [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2012-express).  These are the Express version, which are free to download and use.

Comment: you can find cli .net compilers in the windows SDK as well. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/78f4aasd.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Compilers don't come with the framework installer... there are just the files needed to execute applications built with .NET compilers